# Should I check boost::shared_ptr or std::shared_ptr before I use it?

Tags: c++, boost

```
void f(boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr)
{
    if (ptr) // should we check?
        // do something
}

void f2(int *p)
{
    if (p) // good practice to check before using it
        // do something
}
```

**Question:** Should we validate `shared_ptr` before we use it?

Comment: Just use **use_count** function for checking number of references and there is nothings to check.

Answer (score 5):

No. If it is in the contract of the function that it must be valid, then the quickest way to bring attention to the fact that the caller has a bug is to crash. Fail as early as you can.

Comment: The problem with this is that technically it will only cause UB; there's no guarantee of an _observable_ bug, muchless a crash.

Comment: @ildjarn: "Fail as early as you can" - `assert`. :)

Comment: +1 because it's exactly what I do. Typical smart things that you won't hear in universitary programming courses run by incompetent, non-programmers professors.

Comment: Its the same for any smart or raw pointer, its the contract with the caller that counts. When you say "its ok to call with null ptr" then you check. If you say "calling with null ptr causes UB" then it causes UB. Chose your interface.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: Remvoed comment.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on whether it's actually a possibility during normal program execution that the `shared_ptr` is null. If not, push the responsibility as a precondition on the user of `f` and maybe `assert(ptr);`. Note that it's not only applicable to `shared_ptr`, but any pointer use really. Although you maybe should just use references here.

Comment: I specifically don't list the question by providing a function with reference parameter b/c we assume that reference should not point to an empty pointer and we always don't need to check a reference. However, you still can make it that invalid somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your scenario:

If the `f()` is a public function / API function where you have no control over what someone may pass you then yes you should check.

If the function is a private member function or is documented as requiring a valid pointer then I would use `assert`. It has the bnous of having no overhead in release builds and quickly shows up the problem in debug builds.

```
 void f( shared_ptr<T> ptr)
 {
    assert( ptr && "ptr is null!" );

    .....
 }
```

Comment: Dislike assert for validating runtime values as you get different behavior in debug and release. Assert should be reserved for application invariants not for runtime checks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. shared_ptr just gives you the benefit of it knowing when to release its allocated memory by counting references to it. You should still verify if it is valid before using it, assuming you don't have some other way of knowing beforehand that it will definitely not be null, but that's beside the issue of whether or not you're using a shared_ptr.

Comment: While this is good general advice, it should be noted that, just like other pointers, if the pointer cannot be null because of some program/class invariant, then it needn't be checked.  For example, if the a private member shared pointer is set and checked in the constructor and then is never re-assigned, there is no need to check it in each member function call.

Comment: @André : Or it should be checked in an `assert`.

Comment: @ildjarn: If you place the assert at the **end** of each public method. As the invariant is that after any modification to the object the internal state is consistent and the member has a correct value. Note: Based on Andre comment on private members.

Answer (score 0):

Let say: if your `void foo(shared_ptr<int> ptr)` is a general purpose library and you want to inform the user at runtime that the `nullptr` value is unsupported (throwing an exception) or it is treated with a different codepath yes, it's correct to check for it. If you don't need to store the shared_ptr somewhere with your `foo()` and you just need to ensure the function won't support null pointers, just pass a reference, for example `void foo(int &integer)`. For the compilers I'm aware of, references are most of the times non-nullable pointers (depending often on optimization choices).